# ReactJs: useState's setState calls itself twice

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

I have a toggleInCart function that gets called on a button click, and for the first two calls it works well, but then for some reason the function I pass in to useState to update the cart calls itself twice.

Here's my code:

```
const toggleInCart = (productId) => {
        console.log("toggling");
        setCart((cart) => {
            console.log("setting cart");
            let _itemInCart = cart.filter(
                (item) => item.productId == productId
            );
            if (_itemInCart.length > 0) {
                console.log("in cart");
                return cart.filter((item) => item.productId != productId);
            } else {
                console.log("not in cart");
                let _cart = cart;
                _cart.push({ productId, quantity: 1 });
                return _cart;
            }
        });
        return;
    };
```

here's what I see in dev tools: (the empty brackets are unimportant)

[image: dev tools screenshot]

I'm working in NextJs, and I have React StrictMode off.

I would appreciate help with this, thank you.

Comment: This is probably unrelated but there's a bug in the final branch of the if block. Here you assign a new var to the prev cart and then you push into it. This wont be immutable since even though you reassigned the var, it wont copy the array -- its the same reference. You need  `return [...cart, { productId, quantity: 1 }]`. The rest is ok because `filter` creates a new array.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so I simply restarted my development server and now it works. I think I simply didn't restart it after switching the reactStrictMode to off, because after switching it back on and restarting the weird behavior comes back.